# How can a button change textView color more than once?

Tags: java, android, colors, textview

I'm trying to make it so that a button changes the color of the textView to WHITE, but then on second press changes it to BLUE, and third press to RED and so on. When I try it obviously it chooses just the last (RED) and won't change again. Anyone got any ideas how I can do this? Really stuck. Here's the code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dc1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1);
    bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Handler handler = new RandomMoveHandler((TextView) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1));
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dc1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dc1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            dc1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: you set it in a single block one after another it will change red only

Comment: So how do I make an array for the button?

Comment: Just use a case/switch statement for this one.

Comment: @JasonMills : answers bellow are all corrects ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] colors = {Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Color.RED };

  bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Integer tag = (v.getTag() == null) ? 0 : (Integer)v.getTag();
            int color = colors[tag];
            dc1.setTextColor(color);
            v.setTag((tag+1)%colors.length);
        }
    });
```

I cannot try  now. Check for typo

Comment: Works perfectly! can you tell me if I want to add more colors do I just add them up the top with the others or will I have to change anything else?

Comment: istead of v.setTag((tag+1)%3); put v.setTag((tag+1)%colors.length); then add other colors to the array

Comment: Can you tell me, are WHITE, RED, BLUE, GREEN, CYAN and MAGENTA the only colors I can use? Can I not specify a hex value?

Comment: use Color.parseColor("#YOURHEX") and store the returned value (an int) inside the array

Answer (score 1):

```
private int count = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
dc1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1);
bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

Handler handler = new RandomMoveHandler((TextView) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1));
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

  bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(count)
        {
         case 0: dc1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); count++; break;
         case 1: dc1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE); count++; break;
         case 2: dc1.setTextColor(Color.RED); count = 0; break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable count inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: if you make count final its value can not change

Comment: Integer tag = (v.getTag() == null) ? 0 : (Integer)v.getTag();
                int color = colors[tag];
                dc1.setTextColor(color);
                v.setTag((tag+1)%7);

            }

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 int [] colors = new int[]{Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Color.RED};
    int index = 0;
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dc1.setTextColor(colors[index]);
                index++;
                if(index == colors.length)
                  index = 0;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like a beginner question.
What you're doing right now is that when you click the button, the `onClick()` method is called, then the color is set to white, then blue, then red in a blink of an eye.
what you want to do is something more like the other answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of click, try this:

```
private int flag = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        dc1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1);
        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (flag == 0)
                    dc1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                else if (flag == 1)
                    dc1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                else if (flag == 2)
                    dc1.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                if (flag++ >= 2)
                    flag = 0;
            }
        });
```